# sshfs mounting linux directory from mac stopped working

Tags: linux, macos, sockets, sshfs

Until this morning, I'd been using sshfs quite nicely to mount a directory from a linux machine in my office.  Today, it stopped.  Here's my sshfs command:

```
sshfs -osshfs_sync,volname=linux-builder3 linux-builder3:/home/cnorum /Users/carl/linux-builder3
```

I get this error, but the sshfs process seems to still be running (that is, it just sits there, never returning to the shell prompt):

```
mount_osxfusefs: failed to mount /Users/carl/linux-builder3@/dev/osxfuse1: Socket is not connected
```

The system log on the Mac has these messages:

```
2/20/13 12:57:27.476 PM KernelEventAgent[43]: tid 00000000 received event(s) VQ_DEAD (32)
2/20/13 12:57:27.000 PM kernel[0]: OSXFUSE: force ejecting (no response from user space 5)
2/20/13 12:57:27.000 PM kernel[0]: OSXFUSE: user-space initialization failed (57)
```

And here's `/var/log/auth.log` on the linux machine:

```
Feb 20 12:56:28 linux-builder3 adclient[1599]: INFO  <fd:22 PAMIsUserAllowedAccess> audit User 'cnorum' is authorized
Feb 20 12:56:28 linux-builder3 sshd[29648]: Accepted publickey for cnorum from 10.0.40.65 port 49850 ssh2
Feb 20 12:56:28 linux-builder3 sshd[29648]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user cnorum by (uid=0)
Feb 20 12:56:28 linux-builder3 sshd[29729]: subsystem request for sftp
```

sshfs connections to other machines (linux-builder and linux-builder2 in my case) seem to be fine.  Does anybody have any suggestions for what went wrong and how I might fix it?  I can get any logs you might want to see!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's fixed.  I had this line in the `.bashrc` on the linux box:

```
CLIENT_PATH_PREFIX="$(ssh ${CLIENT_ADDR} 'echo ${SSHFS_PATH_PREFIX}')/$(hostname)/$(whoami)"
```

It didn't need to be run by non-interactive shells, so I pushed that off to a different file, and it's better now.  I don't really understand *why*, but I'm happy it works.

Answer (score 4):

For future googlers, I received this mysterious error and realized the path I was providing to sshfs was non-existent. Oops. Fixed it and I'm off.

```
mount_osxfusefs: failed to mount /Volumes/mypath@/dev/osxfuse0: Socket is not connected
```

Comment: This was very similar to my problem - I had a typo in the host address! Thanks!

Comment: in the same vein, I thought I could use my `.ssh/config` host synonyms in `/etc/fstab` definitions and _without_ specifying an `IdentifyFile=~/.ssh/id_rsa`. Suffice it to say I was sorely mistaken! For the googlers I got (at least) a terse message in my syslog: `OSXFUSE: user-space initialization failed (57)`

Comment: Note: ~/ on a mac is /Users/username/  but the linux computer probably has /home/username/.   Once I changed `sshfs server:~/ ~/mnt_fldr/` to `sshfs server:/home/username/ /Users/username/mnt_fldr/` it worked.

Comment: Similarly, this error can be caused if the remote server cannot be connected to.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the RSA host key for my host changed, so I had to run

```
ssh-keygen -R site.com
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was an offending key in `known_hosts`:

When I tried to SSH into the server, I received:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:<something>
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /Users/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending ECDSA key in /Users/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts:86
RSA host key for <server> has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

Removing the offending key (provided you trust the server), solved the issue.